# Facebook Javascript SDK getLoginStatus invalid response

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

FB JS SDK Version: 'v2.3'

My Facebook account is connected to my Facebook app.
If i call FB.getLoginStatus on my website, the status is "connected", authResponse is properly filled.

On another browser or tab i open my Facebook application settings and remove the app.
Back to my website, i call FB.getLoginStatus again. Status is still "connected".
It remains the same for a very long time.

If i refresh the page and FB.init runs again, FB.getLoginStatus gives proper "not_authorized" status response.

How can i get the current login status properly with FB.getLoginStatus, without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Why) have you not read the documentation of the method …?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/#servers:

> “To improve the performance of your application, not every call to check the status of the user will result in request to Facebook's servers. Where possible, the response is cached. The first time in the current browser session that `FB.getLoginStatus` is called, or the JS SDK is init'd with `status: true`, the response object will be cached by the SDK. Subsequent calls to `FB.getLoginStatus` will return data from this cached response.
>
> This can cause problems where the user has logged into (or out of) Facebook since the last full session lookup, or if the user has removed your application in their account settings.
>
> To get around this, you call `FB.getLoginStatus` with the second parameter set to `true` to force a roundtrip to Facebook - effectively refreshing the cache of the response object.”

Comment: You are right, totally my fault. Thanks for helping me out despite my laziness.